# Create Object with Foreign key with Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I want to create a feedback object with serializer:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    img_small = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    img_large = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'location'

class Schedules(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, models.DO_NOTHING, default=None)
    detail = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'schedules'

class Feedbacks(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, models.DO_NOTHING)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedules, models.DO_NOTHING)
    start = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    end = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'feedbacks'
```

and the serializer class:

```
class FeedbackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Location.objects.all())
    schedule_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Schedules.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Feedbacks
        fields = ('location_id', 'schedule_id', 'start', 'end')
        # read_only_fields = ('location_id', 'schedule_id')
```

My data is

```
{"location_id" : 2, "schedule_id" : 2, "start" : "1", "end" : 2}
```

The problem is that after validation my validated_data contain Location and Schedule object, not the id so I cannot insert and get this error

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Location'
```

Comment: And does this works? - `location_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), source='location')`

Comment: yes it works. Thank you very much. But can you explain a little bit about how this works? As I understand the "source" keyword tell me which attribute of the model that the field belongs to. But if I don't need to do it with start and end, why are location_id and schedule_id different?

Comment: To understand the actual problem you need to know how django models work when you defined a ForeignKey field. For example, if you define `location` as FK, then behind the scene you get also a `location_id` which is the actual id of that (not the instance, which is on the `location` field). You can try printing these fields on your `Feedback` object and see the difference. Getting back in the serializer if you put `location_id` it expects an id of it not an instance of `Location` (which you get because that is returned by `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` after validation), thus you get the error.

Comment: @GabrielMuj I kind of understand the concept now but for me, it still feels a little bit weird. The validation process knows that location_id is an int, that refers to the id of location object, but still return the object anyway.

Comment: @NhatTon even if you send the id you get back the object because of the method `to_internal_value` from `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`. That method use the `queryset` and then does a `get` on the id (you can check out the source code of it). So the actual result that you get back is the instance of `Location`. Just for testing and learning purposes try to use `IntegerField` (if your primary keys are int) for the `location_id`, that should work since it will be translated to int not the location instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this, it works too. I'm half confused.

```
class FeedbackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Location.objects.all())
    schedule = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Schedules.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Feedbacks
        fields = ('location', 'schedule', 'start', 'end')
```

Comment: I may have figured this out. Apparently, to deserialize I don't even need the attribute, just need to change fields location_id to location and schedule_id to schedule